# Random color border-bottom in :after element

Tags: javascript

The links in my navigation have a border-bottom hover animation that I'm hoping to apply random colours to. **[This](https://jsfiddle.net/452LLs8e/1/)** is the entire code so far, but I'm specifically referring to this:

```
#navigation li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

#navigation li a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Instead of "border-bottom: 2px solid #000", I'd like for the border to be a random colour from an array (#ff86b1, #d162ff, #9cbdff and #4fff4f, if that makes a difference). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anyone else trying to do this in particular, so any pointers would be super appreciated.

Comment: I can spot the problem right away: even though you added the tag `javascript`, there is none in your fiddle.

Comment: Would you like to get random color only once for page loading, or everytime user hovers links?

Comment: @RadLexus: I would like to apply Javascript, but I haven't been able to find an appropriate script.

Comment: @jodietbh Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: @br3t I'd prefer each link to have its own colour when hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following jQuery code:

```
$("#navigation li a").each(function(){
var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"]; //include your own colors
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
$(this).css("borderColor", colors[rand]);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Cheers!!

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to include the jQuery library or it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to write some javascript code.
I have done it using jQuery so you have to include jQuery liberary in your project.

https://jsfiddle.net/452LLs8e/2/

Updated CSS is :
    a {
      text-decoration:none
    }
    #navigation {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position:relative;
    line-height:24px;
    }

```
#navigation ul {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style:None;
}

#navigation li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
list-style:None;
vertical-align: super;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
text-align:center;
}

#navigation li a {
font-size: 9px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
margin-bottom:-8px;
letter-spacing:2px;
color:#000;
}

#navigation li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

#navigation li a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Javascript Code :

```
var arrColor=['#ff86b1', '#d162ff', '#9cbdff', '#4fff4f'];

var randIdx=parseInt(Math.random()*arrColor.length);

$('#navigation li a').css('border-color',arrColor[randIdx]);
console.log(arrColor[randIdx]);
```

Comment: Make a note that color with update only on page refresh.